# Referring to a 3rd-party Magento extension as an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

If question submitted on the forum can be solved by a 3rd-party Magento extension is it allowed to post a link to the extension as an answer? Also, is it allowed to post a link to an external blog post describing a solution using the extension?

Answer (score 8):

Posting 3rd party extension links as answers is allowed but some restrictions apply.
The answer should not contain just a link.
So answers like

> This extension will solve your problem {extension link here}.

You have to explain in a few words what the extension does, how it works, and why would it solve the problem.
Also, if all or almost all of your answers contain links to extensions, specially paid extensions and from the same vendor then your account will probably get suspended.

Also, it is ok to post links to blogs but the main idea in the blog post should be reproduced in the answer. There is no guarantee that the blogpost will be there 1 year from now.
The same rules for third party extension answer apply to blog posts. If all/most of your answers contain links to the same blog it may be considered as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an extension link as an answer without including any explanation is not allowed as it is like promoting your own product/content and it is indeed a low quality answer or spam.

The link only answer are also not valid, as it would be helpful only till the link/blog exist. Such answer will be flagged and deleted.
You should [check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/) for more help.

Comment: "Posting an extension link as an answer is not allowed". It is allowed to a certain extend. Read Marius his answer.